# How do I redirect /about to /foo/index.php/pages/about with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do I redirect this single page
/about
to
/foo/index.php/pages/about
, without changing url in browser?

This works:

```
RewriteRule "^about$" "/foo/index.php/pages/about" [R]
```

But it changes url in the browser, which is not what I needed.

I tried writing this:

```
RewriteRule "^about$" "/foo/index.php/pages/about"
```

or

```
RewriteRule "^about$" "/foo/index.php/pages/about" [QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule "^about$" "/foo/index.php/pages/about" [QSD]
```

but all of them displays the "404 Page Not Found" page from CodeIgniter (not the Apache default one).
Also the error log of CodeIgniter says "404 Page Not Found: About/index".

Looks like it's redirected to /foo/index.php/about instead, but can't figure out a way to solve it.

Comment: Have you set some routes in routes.php and also have you followed codeigniter class and filenaming way http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: The target url and the whole site works fine. Just can't get the redirection done.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this.

In `.htaccess`, add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^about$ /foo/index.php
```

In CodeIgniter's `routes.php`, add this route:

```
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
```

Accessing `/about` will be redirected to `/foo/index.php`, and then CodeIgniter will treat `about` in the url as the controller, and route to `pages/about` which is normally accessible from `/foo/index.php/pages/about`.

It seems that CodeIgniter ignores anything after `index.php` in RewriteRule, and treats whatever in the actual url as the controller, can't figure out why though.

This does not look like a formal solution, but at least it makes the redirection to work like expected.